# Revoke Create Table From Schema In Snowflake DWH

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Use Case**

Create a new role which only has `SELECT` access to all tables in all the schema, but also mustn't be able to create tables in the respective database and schema.

**Script**

```
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
CREATE ROLE DUMMY_ROLE;

GRANT ROLE DUMMY_ROLE TO USER "myself@gmail.com"

GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH TO ROLE DUMMY_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE PRD_DWH TO ROLE DUMMY_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA PRD_DWH.ANALYTICS TO ROLE DUMMY_ROLE;
```

**Issue**

Once I create the role above and I assume that role, it is still allowing me to create table, despite not granting the `CREATE TABLE` privilege permission.

```
USE ROLE DUMMY_ROLE;
CREATE TABLE PRD_DWH.ANALYTICS.DELETEME (ID INTEGER);
```

This also doesn't work even if I am revoking `CREATE TABLE` explicitly (aka allows me to create tables in `DUMMY_ROLE`):

```
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
REVOKE CREATE TABLE ON SCHEMA PRD_DWH.ANALYTICS FROM ROLE DUMMY_ROLE;
```

I had like to understand how can I prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any grants to the PUBLIC role?

```
show grants to role PUBLIC;
```

As you may know, the PUBLIC role is automatically given to and can be accessed by every user. So you'll want to make sure this role isn't gaining the permissions you're trying to test and revoke accordingly from the PUBLIC role.